# Implementing chat messaging using firebase

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm creating a type of chat messaging app using firebase. I'm following firebase documentation and the codelab links for the samples, but I'm stuck at one point before the chatting part.

I ask the user to login to his Google+ account using Google+ api in my app, then they have to connect which will send invites to whomsoever they wish. I implemented it as per this [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#10). It is indeed sending out a mail to that user as a invitation request, but I'm not able to understand what is supposed to happen once they click on invite. Or how will the two user start conversing with each other?

May be I'm missing out some crucial steps, please help me out.